# Aggregation on multiple fields - elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

How to use multiple aggregation in elasticsearch. My code works for single aggregation but I want to add another aggregation. I use another aggs for that but its parsing an exception.

```
 { "aggs": {
                "_figures": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "id"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "field1": {
                      "stats": {
                        "field": "field1"
                      },
                      "field2":{
                        "stats":{
                          "field":"field2"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
```

Comment: You need to put field2 parallel to field1 "aggs": {
        "field1": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "field1"
          }
        },
        "field2": {
          "stats": {
            "field": "field2"
          }
        }
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me now. Using below code I can work with multiple aggregations

```
 {"aggs": {
        "emp_figures": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "id"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "field1": {
              "stats": {
                "field": "field1"
              }
            },
            "field2":{
                "stats":{
                  "field":"field2"
                }
              },
            "field3":{
                "stats":{
                  "field":"field3"
                }
              }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

And also this is the way to works with multiple aggregation with java

```
 SearchResponse getResponse = 
        client.prepareSearch( ElasticSearchConstants.INDEX ).setTypes( ElasticSearchConstants.TBL)
            .addAggregation( AggregationBuilders.terms( FIGURE)
                                    .field( "id" )
            .subAggregation( AggregationBuilders.stats( "stats" ).field( field1 ) )
            .subAggregation( AggregationBuilders.stats( "stats" ).field( field2) ).size( 100 ) )
                            .setQuery( query )
                            .setFrom( 0 )
                            .execute().actionGet();
```